# How to serialize a class with one of its members holding instance of another class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class as below:

```
public class ItemGroup
{
    public int type;
    public Item[] item;
}

public class Item
{
    public string name;
    public int category;
}
```

I would like to convert ItemGroup into an XML like this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <type>1</type>
    <Item>
        <name>HELLO</name>
        <category>1</category>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <name>WORLD</name>
        <category>2</category>
    </Item>
</ItemGroup>
```

What XML Tag need to used to specified in the class? I am using C#

Comment: Are you already leveraging the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to construct/read the basic XML and just asking which attributes to adorn the class to achieve the exact XML schema you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps counter-intuitively, you only need to use the [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attribute. This instructs the `XmlSerializer` to build the `Item` sets one-by-one after each other which will match the spec you provided. In addition, you need to specify the element name explicitly since your field is lower case "item", but you want to have upper case "Item".

```
public class ItemGroup
{
    public int type;

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public Item[] item;
}

public class Item
{
    public string name;
    public int category;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I have been using the wrong attribute [XMLArray] and [XMLArrayItem].  Any suggestion of good tutorial and/or example to further understand how this XML serialization work? Thanks

Comment: @IreneLee You can google around for usages and tutorials (for example: http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization). I only suggest that you implement your own mini-wrappers (with generics if possible) around it to simplify all the setup/wiring/disposing code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to not create the xml manually, but serialize the class using this simple code:

```
     XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
     StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(myxml.xml);
     mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, objectToSerialize);
     myWriter.Close();
```

In some cases you should apply SerializableAttribute to your class.